# Ubuntu/Debian client don't use NFSv4

Tags: ubuntu, debian, nfs4

I'm try to create a connection to a [NFSv4 only](https://wiki.debian.org/NFSServerSetup) server.
But the clients try to downgrade the protocol versions:

```
mount -v -t nfs -o nfsvers=4 my-nfsv4-only.server:/exports/storagetest storagetest
mount.nfs: timeout set for Wed Oct 27 16:16:28 2021
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4,addr=XX.XX.XX.XX,clientaddr=YY.YY.YY.YY'
mount.nfs: mount(2): No such file or directory
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'addr=XX.XX.XX.XX'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying XX.XX.XX.XX prog 100003 vers 3 prot TCP port 2049
mount.nfs: portmap query retrying: RPC: Program/version mismatch
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=17
mount.nfs: portmap query failed: RPC: Program not registered
mount.nfs: requested NFS version or transport protocol is not supported
```

Server is a fresh Debian 11, clients are Ubuntu 20.04 and Debian 11. Same issue.

Any idea?